# Obtain stock prices in parallel using nsetools based on csv data

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, csv, financial

```
import time
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from nsetools import Nse

nse = Nse()
t = time.time()
FILE_LOCATION = ''  # csv file, blank because path not relevant to others
df = pd.read_csv(FILE_LOCATION)
```

## CSV File contents:

```
Instrument,Qty,Avg buy price
APLAPOLLO,3,949.95
AVANTIFEED,6,554.55
BALAMINES,9,337.72
BALMLAWRIE,4,258.5
BANCOINDIA,15,217
DCMSHRIRAM,12,261.4
GHCL,12,267.2
GIPCL,27,101.95
JAMNAAUTO,15,182.1
JBCHEPHARM,15,344.85
KEI,24,143.95
KPRMILL,6,569.65
KRBL,9,312
MPHASIS,6,533.95
SHEMAROO,2,413.25
```

## Code:

```
# using argparse to provide options for obtaining closePrice or buyPrice1
# of stocks
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Stock Quote fetcher')
parser.add_argument('-r', '--realtime', help='Obtain realtime stock\
                    quotes', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()


def get_closing(stock):
    """Function to obtain closePrice or buyPrice1 of stocks"""
    if args.realtime:
        return nse.get_quote(stock)['buyPrice1']
    else:
        return nse.get_quote(stock)['closePrice']


# calculating current value of investment
current_value = sum(get_closing(row[0]) * row[1] for index, row in
                    df.iterrows())

print(current_value)
print("Completed in ", time.time() - t)
```

Currently the stock prices are obtained sequentially using the generator expression. Doing this takes 18-25 seconds to calculate the current value of investment. Is there any way to obtain these prices all together in parallel and calculate current value of investment?

Comment: problem can be `nse` which need some time to get data. Maybe it can get many stocks in one request.

Comment: There is no functionality provided by nsetools to obtain prices of multiple stocks in one request.

Comment: Parallelize the process, don't know how many connections could you open with nse. but you can fork into N process who ask only one sock and save it into the csv as additional column, wait for all to finish, and then do the sum.

Comment: Since these are file transfers over the internet (I assume) they are I/O bound and multiple threads work fine to transfer the files.

Answer (score 1):

I have forked the repository [here](https://github.com/Arkoprabho/NSEToolsPy), where I have been working on moving the `nsetools` API to a `DataFrame`-based approach and using threads to reduce the time it takes to fetch multiple quotes.

The latest release as of today `v1.1.0` currently has all these features implemented.

However, `python2` compatibility is not guaranteed. If you wish to request for any more features, be sure to create a new issue. I will work on it and keep updating the repo.

Comment: I tried visiting the link, github says page not found

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I have update the link. Kindly check

Comment: The link for detailed documentation throws 404 not found error

Comment: Yes.I am aware of it. There is an open issue for it too. I haven't been able to work on generating the documentation. It would be of great help if one can start a PR with the proper documentation. The code is commented properly with docstrings, so documentation would be just a matter of invoking proper commands with sphinx (or any alternate)